# Using request level context in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm looking for a way to set request level context in Tornado.
This is useful for logging purpose, to print some request attributes with every log line (like `user_id`).
I'd like to populate the context in `web.RequestHandler` and then access it in other coroutines that this request called.

```
class WebRequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        RequestContext.test_mode = self.application.settings.get('test_mode', False)
        RequestContext.corr_id = self.request.header.get('X-Request-ID')

        result = yield some_func()

        self.write(result)


@gen.coroutine
def some_func()
    if RequestContext.test_mode:
        print "In test mode"

    do more async calls
```

Currently I pass `context` object (`dict` with values) to every async function call down stream, this way every part of the code can do monitoring and logging with right context.
I'm looking for a cleaner/simpler solution.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1):

The concept of request context doesn't really hold well in async frameworks (especially if you have high volume traffic) for the simple fact that there could potentially be hundreds of concurrent requests and it becomes difficult to determine which "context" to use. This works for sequential frameworks like Flask, Falcon, Django, etc. because requests are handled one by one and it's simple to determine which request you're dealing with.

The preferred method of handling functionality between a request start and end is to override [`prepare`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.prepare) and [`on_finish`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_finish) respectively.

```
class WebRequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):

    def prepare(self):
        print('Logging...prepare')
        if self.application.settings.get('test_mode', False):
            print("In test mode")
        print('X-Request-ID: {0}'.format(self.request.header.get('X-Request-ID')))

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        result = yield some_func()
        self.write(result)

    def on_finish(self):
        print('Logging...on_finish')
```

The simple solution would be to create an object that represents the context of your request and pass that into your log function. Example:

```
class RequestContext(object):
    """
    Hold request context
    """

class WebRequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        # create new context obj and fill w/ necessary parameters
        request_context = RequestContext()
        request_context.test_mode = self.application.settings.get('test_mode', False)
        request_context.corr_id = self.request.header.get('X-Request-ID')

        # pass context objects into coroutine
        result = yield some_func(request_context)

        self.write(result)


@gen.coroutine
def some_func(request_context)
    if request_context.test_mode:
        print "In test mode"

    # do more async calls
```

Comment: Currently I'm implementing `RequestContext` concept by pushing a context object (`dict` with values) to all async function calls.
It works OK, even in high traffic. Tornado does manage `StackContext` to be able to resume from `yield`, I wish there could be a way to create some kind of `GlobalStackContext` that is visible to all `yield` calls inside the request.